# this.forceUpdate and passing state through React-Router-DOM Link component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I solved my own problem already but I have no clue as to what's happening and why it works.

I have a `Link` component that links to the same page it's currently on, but for a different product. So the same component but displaying a different product.

```
<Link to={directUrl} onClick={() => this.forceUpdate} state={{ urlPicture: picture }}>
```

Do note `<Link>` is in a sub-component, not the main component it routes to itself.

Because it routes to the same page, `Link` doesn't automatically refresh the page. To solve this I added `onClick={() => this.forceUpdate}`, but now my state didn't pass properly. I checked this with the following lines of code in the other component.

```js
location = useLocation()
const [ firstImage, setFirstImage ] = useState(location.state?.urlPicture || null)
console.log(`here is ${mainPicture}`) //mainPicture is just a string
```

However, when I replace `onClick={() => this.forceUpdate}` with `onClick={() => window.location.reload()}`, then my state does pass properly through the `Link`.

I do know that there is a difference between the 2 and that `this.forceUpdate` is the lighter of the 2, but to my knowledge it should refresh the component and update its state. I don't see why it's not sufficient and honestly I have no clue why it's working the way it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[forceUpdate](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) is a function, so it needs to be called in order to have any effect.

Won't work:

```js
onClick={() => this.forceUpdate} // <-- not invoked!!
```

Should work:

```js
onClick={() => this.forceUpdate()} // <-- invoked
```

or

```js
onClick={this.forceUpdate} // <-- passed as click handler and invoked
```

This is why your `onClick={() => window.location.reload()}` code *does* actually work, though it reloads the entire app which is very likely unwanted behavior.

This said, in almost 100% of the cases if you are reaching out for `forceUpdate` to force trigger a component to rerender you are doing something incorrectly. The `Link` likely is rerendering the component, but the component doesn't appear to be "reacting" to the route state change. The component being passed the route state should handle it within the React component lifecycle. In this case it would be the use of the `React.useEffect` hook to re-synchronize the local component state with the passed route state.

Example:

```js
const { state } = useLocation();

const [firstImage, setFirstImage] = useState(state?.urlPicture || null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (state?.urlPicture) {
    setFirstImage(state.urlPicture);
  }
}, [state]);
```

It is, however, generally considered a bit of a React anti-pattern to store passed state/props/etc into local state. Use these values directly in the component, memoizing them if necessary.

Examples:

```js
const { state } = useLocation();

const firstImage = state?.urlPicture || null;
```

```js
const { state } = useLocation();

const firstImage = useMemo(() => state?.urlPicture || null, [state]);
```

In fact, just about any time you have coded a `useState`-`useEffect` coupling you should really just use the `useMemo` hook.

Comment: In my experience, ```() => this.forceUpdate``` with or without the ```()``` does not behave differently. I had already tried all 3 variations. What you say is probably true, but the problem does not lie there. The answer you gave works and is indeed the most desired outcome, the better way to handle it. You saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: Why my own code not works though is still unexplained. But reading your answer I think I found the reason. ```this.forceUpdate()``` is called in a subcomponent, not the main component itself. So only the component where the Link resides gets updated, not the component that contains firstImage and displays it.

Comment: @StackerCen Well, like I said, the `Link` component effecting a navigation action is likely already rerendering the UI, but the issue isn't the rerendering part, it's the handling the passed state in the navigation transition part. Right, I think you are correct that you may only be force rendering the nested/child component and *not* the ancestor component higher up the ReactTree.

Answer (score 0):

As said, Link resides in a sub-component, not the main component it routes to itself. When `this.forceUpdate` is called, `this` is referring to the sub component and only that will get "force updated". The component with 'firstImage' won't get refreshed.